# Intersection of Level Curves and a Ellipse at a given angle

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am preparing for an exam and I'm going over previous administered tests.  I have come across the following problem and have little idea how to tackle it.  It goes as follows:

> Let $f(x,y)=2x^2-y^2$. Some of the level sets of $f$ intersect the curve $2x^2 + y^2 = 1$.
>   Find the equation of a level set of $f$ whose tangent line at a point of intersection
>   forms a $60$ degree angle with the tangent line of the ellipse at that intersection point.

My attempt at a solution begins and ends with the using the gradient of $f(x,y)$ to somehow calculate the dot product between that and the ellipse.  But I don't know if that's the right approach because I get lost after that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, here's a picture of the ellipse and a (rough & guessed) sketch of the level set we're looking for.

[image: MSEPIC]

Now, we know that if at the point of intersection the tangent lines form a $60^0$ angle, so will the normal lines (a.k.a the gradients). This can be seen by the following:

$$\textrm{Tangent Angle}_1-\textrm{Tangent Angle}_2 = 60^0$$

$$\textrm{Gradient Angle}_1-\textrm{Gradient Angle}_2 = (\textrm{Tangent Angle}_1 + 90^0)-(\textrm{Tangent Angle}_2+90^0) = 60^0$$

So that means that, letting the 'gradient' of that ellipse at any point be $\nabla y$

$$
\begin{align*}
\cos(60^0) = \frac{1}{2} &=\frac{\nabla f \cdot \nabla y}{|\nabla f||\nabla y|}\\
&= \frac{16x^2-4y^2}{16x^2+4y^2} 
\end{align*}
$$

And, finally doing some algebra, we get,

$$8x^2-6y^2=0$$

From here, we just need to find the points on the ellipse that satisfy this equation, because those will also be the points at which the level set of $f$ (which we will find through this) intersect the ellipse.

Remembering that the equation of the ellipse is $1=2x^2+y^2 \implies 8x^2=4-4y^2$,
we plug it into what we got before.

$$(4-4y^2)-6y^2=0 \implies y^2 = \frac{2}{5}$$

And so by plugging that back into the equation for the ellipse, we find that
$2x^2 = 3/5$.

Finally, we put those two ($x$ and $y$) back into the function $f$ to get the level set we were looking for.

$$2x^2-y^2=\frac{3}{5}-\frac{2}{5}=\frac{1}{5}=f$$

So the level curve we were looking for was $\boxed{f(x,y)=\frac{1}{5}}$

Comment: Thanks!  Didn't realize how simple the solution actually was in the end.  Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Well you were on track already, so that was a good. I hope you do well on your exam!